# ASP.Net MVC 4 Kendo UI Scheduler multiple events get added when update event

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I'm new to kendo Ui. I've used the scheduler control in my ASP.Net MVC 4 project and implemented using Ajax calls as defined in following tutorial.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/scheduler/ajax-editing.

My problem is when I try to edit an event, it will edit the event, plus creates one or more duplicate records in the database with the same data. How should I avoid it.

Following is my Index.cshtml

```
@(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<Portal.Presentation.Web.BoundedContext.QC.MVC.Areas.Razor.Models.LeavePlan>()
  .Name("scheduler")
.Date(DateTime.Now)
.Height(600)
.AllDaySlot(true)
.Views(views =>
{
    views.DayView();
    views.WeekView(weekView => weekView.Selected(true));
    views.MonthView();
})
.Timezone("Etc/UTC")
.Resources(resource =>
{
    resource.Add(m => m.PlanTypeId)
        .Title("Plan Type")
        .DataTextField("Text")
        .DataValueField("Value")
        .DataColorField("Color")
        .BindTo(new[] { 
            new { Text = "Annual Leave", Value = 1, Color = "#f8a398" } ,
            new { Text = "Casual Leave", Value = 2, Color = "#51a0ed" } ,
            new { Text = "Sick Leave", Value = 2, Color = "#55a098" } ,
            new { Text = "Travel", Value = 3, Color = "#56ca85" } 
        });
})
.DataSource(d => d
    .Model(m => {
        m.Id(f => f.TaskID);
        m.Field(f => f.ResourceId).DefaultValue(1);
        //Set the recurrence ID field from the model:
        //m.RecurrenceId(f => f.RecurrenceID);
    })
    .Read("Tasks_Read", "LeavePlan")
    .Create("Tasks_Create", "LeavePlan")
    .Destroy("Tasks_Destroy", "LeavePlan")
    .Update("Tasks_Update", "LeavePlan")
))
```

Following is my update method.

```
  public ActionResult Tasks_Update([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, LeavePlan leave)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

                // Create a new Task entity and set its properties from the posted TaskViewModel
            var entity = new ResourceLeavePlan
                {
                    StartDate = leave.Start
                    ,Title = leave.Title
                    ,EndDate = leave.End.ToUniversalTime()
                    ,ResourceLeavePlanId = (int)leave.TaskID
                    ,IsAllDay=leave.IsAllDay
                    ,RecurrenceId=leave.ResourceId
                    ,Description=leave.Description
                    ,RecurrenceException=leave.RecurrenceException
                    ,LeaveTypeId=(int)leave.PlanTypeId
                    ,ResourceId = resourceId
                };

            _resourceLeavePlanService.Update(entity);
            }

        return Json(new[] { leave }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }
```

And help on this would be appreciated.

The model is same as the model in the tutorial in the above link.

and also would be grateful if some one can explain me the use of "RecurrenceId" in the scheduler

Answer (score 1):

You are just missing unique **TaskID** in your entity object.

```
    var entity = new ResourceLeavePlan
    {

    TaskID = leave.TaskID // Just try adding this line please and it would work

    ,StartDate = leave.Start
    ,Title = leave.Title
    ,EndDate = leave.End.ToUniversalTime()
    ,ResourceLeavePlanId = (int)leave.TaskID
    ,IsAllDay=leave.IsAllDay
    ,RecurrenceId=leave.ResourceId
    ,Description=leave.Description
    ,RecurrenceException=leave.RecurrenceException
    ,LeaveTypeId=(int)leave.PlanTypeId
    ,ResourceId = resourceId
    };
```

Comment: I had this same problem and this fixed my problem